# How to perform >= or <= conditions with date in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe named df1 and one variable named start date and I have given the dt for both the dataframe and Date variable. the important thing to check out here is both the length of dataframe and date variable are different

```
df1
```

[image]

Date Variable

[image]

we need to filter the data in dataframe df1 based dates for df1 greater than or equal to dates in Date variable.

simply `df['Date'] >= Date variable`

Comment: Can you convert them to a datetime object? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: You meant to have those pictures in the question, right?

Comment: s the pictures represent the data for our opertion

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the approach below ?

```
df.loc[df['Date'] >= Date variable]
```

You need to ensure that that the values in the Series Date and the 'Date variable' are of the same datatype, either `Datetime` or `Date` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare dates, but you have to be sure they are the proper type first.
With Pandas you can enforce the datetime type by doing:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Once both your `df` and the `date_variable` are ok, then you can filter by:

```
filtered = df[df['Date'] >= date_variable['Date']]
```

Here I am assuming that "Date variable" is a dataframe called `date_variable` with a columns `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code snippet very helpful

```
period= (df['date'] >= start_date) & (df['date'] <= end_date)
df_filtered = df.loc[period]
```